# Change GtkTreeView styling to be Windows-like

Tags: gtk

[image]

How can I make GtkTreeView look like on the picture above? Note the tree guides (dotted lines) and folder expander icons.

Answer (score 1):

Tree guides are controlled by `enable-tree-lines` property. Rendering icons is a bit more complicated.

First of all, you will have to add an extra field to model with icon-names. Next, you must connect to `"row-collapsed"` and `"row-expanded"` signals and manually change icon names in your model.

Then you make a TreeViewColumn and pack 2 renderers there with `gtk_tree_view_column_pack_start`.

```
column = gtk_tree_view_column_new ();
gtk_tree_view_column_set_title (column, "title");

renderer0 = gtk_cell_renderer_pixbuf_new ();
g_object_set (renderer0, "icon-name", "folder-open", NULL); // #1
gtk_tree_view_column_pack_start (column, renderer0, FALSE);
gtk_tree_view_column_set_visible (column, TRUE);

renderer1 = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
gtk_tree_view_column_pack_start (column, renderer1, FALSE);
gtk_tree_view_column_set_attributes (column, renderer1, // #2
                                     "text", NAME_COL,
                                     NULL);
```

This snippet uses one icon for all rows (icon-name is set globally), but you can make it get icon-names from model.

If stock icons are not sufficient, you will have to use a GIcon or pixbuf, take a look at `"gicon"` and `"pixbuf"` properties of cellrendererpixbuf

---

EDIT: if the question was about +/- buttons instead of triangles, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820151/how-to-manually-draw-the-gtktreeview-expander) or adjust gtk3 theme